# Name 'option_id' is not defined

Tags: python, django, postgresql

В Django 2.1.7 создаю модель для субд postgresql. Мне нужно, чтобы поля (question_id, option_id) таблицы
'options_selection'  вместе были уникальными. Когда я делаю миграцию выводит ошибку о том, что поля не определены ( Name 'question_id' is not defined).
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно решить эту проблему. Вот сам код, который я написал

```
class qusetions(models.Model):   
    question_name = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
    question_type = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'qusetions'

class options_selection(models.Model):  
    question_id = models.ForeignKey(qusetions, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    option_id = models.IntegerField()
    option_name = models.TextField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'options_selection'
        unique_together = ((question_id, option_id),)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ был непредсказуемым, в unique_together названия полей должны были заключаться в кавычках ))

```
unique_together = (('question_id', 'option_id'),)
```

Comment: А что непредсказуемого-то? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together